# unix: how to cat from 2 inputs?

Tags: unix, cat

in UNIX scripting programming, cat is a command that could combine 2 files together:

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

this generate the 3rd by combining the first two.

also, cat could be used with pipe:

```
cat file1 | tail -4
```

this will list the last 4 lines of file 1.

question: how could I combine the last 4 lines of file 1 and 2, to generate file 3?

i'm a bit lost here: how to give 2 streams inputs to cat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash has a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) feature:

```
  cat <(tail -4 file1) <(tail -4 file2)
```

I often use this feature to diff slightly altered versions of two files.

Answer (score 8):

You could do the following (in bash):

```
(tail -4 file1; tail -4 file2) > file3
```

This doesn't use cat as per your question but it does achieve the goal you describe.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
cat file1 | tail -4 > ./file3; cat file2 | tail -4 >> ./file3
```

?

Comment: In that case you could use: `tail -4 file1 > ./file3; tail -4 ./file2 >> ./file3` (just using tail and not cat/tail)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pee` from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) to do this. Here's my solution

```
pee 'tail file1' 'tail file2' </dev/null > file3
```

Comment: This one works with commands that never finish, like "tail -f"